# API MoySklad Входящий запрос не соответствует формату JSON

Tags: python, json, requests, moysklad-json-api

Использую python 3.7, библиотеку requests. Мой код

```html
url = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/cashout/'
auth = ('login', 'pass')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
body = {"organization": {
            "meta": {
                "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/organization/b66837ad-d66c-11e6-7a69-9711004b5836",
                "metadataHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/organization/metadata",
                "type": "organization",
                "mediaType": "application/json",
                }},
        "agent": {
            "meta": {
                "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/counterparty/0419873a-b878-11e6-7a31-d0fd002a0c98",
                "metadataHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/counterparty/metadata",
                "type": "counterparty",
                "mediaType": "application/json",
               }},
        "expenseItem": {
            "meta": {
                "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/expenseitem/4e50ea24-0673-11e6-97e5-0cc47a342c9e",
                "metadataHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/expenseitem/metadata",
                "type": "expenseitem",
                "mediaType": "application/json"
            }}
        }

r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=body)
response = json.loads(r.content)
response = json.dumps(response, indent=4)
print(response)
```

В ответ получаю ошибку

```html
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "error": "Ошибка формата: входящий запрос не соответствует формату JSON",
            "code": 2001,
            "moreInfo": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc#обработка-ошибок-2001",
            "line": 1,
            "column": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное дело в том, что `body` - словарь и перед отправкой нужно преобразовать его в  JSON. Requests может сделать это. Попробуйте так (обратите внимание на `json=body`):

```
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, json=body)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Поправка json=body сработала